# How to correctly override BasicDataSource for Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jdbc

Currently I have following basic data source in Spring:

```
<bean id="dbcpDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?relaxAutoCommit=true" />
    ...
</bean>
```

Now I need to provide custom data source based on server environment (not config), for which I need to calculate `driverClassName` and `url` fields based on some condition.

I tried overriding `createDataSource()` method:

```
public class MyDataSource extends BasicDataSource {

    @Override
    protected synchronized DataSource createDataSource() throws SQLException {
        if(condition) {
            super.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            super.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?relaxAutoCommit=true");
        } else {
            //...
        }
        return super.createDataSource();
    }
}
```

Which works, but I noticed that `createDataSource()` is getting called each time a query is executed(?), so I would rather move my condition testing elsewhere.

I tried overriding `setDriverClassName()` and `setUrl()` which also works and is getting called only once from what I can tell, but then I need to provide some values in Spring configuration in order to trigger those setters as they are not called otherwise:

```
<bean id="dbcpDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="whatever" />
    <property name="url" value="whatever" />
    ...
</bean>
```

which might look confusing.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation of `BasicDataSource`?

Comment: I think that's where you should start investigating, don't you think? :)

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to extend `BasicDataSource`. Inheritance is the strongest form of coupling and should be avoided unless you have a real reason to use it.

You have two options:

- Create a wrapper (use composition instead of inheritance)

  ```
  public class MyDataSource implements DataSource {
      private BasicDataSource target = new BasicDataSource();
      public MyDataSource() {
          if (condition) {
              target.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");                
              target.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?relaxAutoCommit=true"); 
          } else { ... }
      }
      public Connection getConnection() {
          return target.getConnection();
      }
      ... etc ...
  }
  ```
- Create a factory (since you need to customize only the creation phase of the object, you don't need to control the whole lifetime of it).

  ```
   public class MyDataSourceFactory {
      public DataSource createDataSource() {
          BasicDataSource target = new BasicDataSource();
          if (condition) {
              target.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");                
              target.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?relaxAutoCommit=true"); 
          } else { ... }
          return target;
      }
  }
  ```

  .

  ```
  <bean id = "factory" class = "MyDataSourceFactory" />
  <bean id = "dbcpDataSource" 
       factory-bean = "factory" factory-method = "createDataSource">
       <property ... />
  </bean>
  ```

**EDIT:** Note that you still can configure the object obtained from the factory as a regular Spring bean.

Also if your condition is simple enough, you can avoid writing your own code at all by using declarative approaches provided by Spring, such as [Spring Expression language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html).

Comment: So instead of extending BasicDataSource you propose to create a copy of it? That seems like more work than needed... I still need default behavior from BasicDataSource (with some properties set through spring configs), just with custom conditions for those two fields.

Comment: @serg: If so, take a look at the factory approach - other properties can still be configured.