# Reading value from file into applicationContext.xml file

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I have a spring based web application and in my application context xml file, I have defined a bean which has all the parameters to connect to database. As part of this bean, for one of the parameters, I have a password key, as shown in the below example and I wanted the value should come from a /vault/password file. This /vault/password is not part of the project/application. This /vault/password will be there in host machine by default.

What is the syntax in applicationContext.xml bean definition, to read a value from a file outside of application context.

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="/vault/password" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I think you're *really* asking this question: "How does a Flyway bean read a password from an external file in order to authenticate?".

Comment: It's not about flyway bean. My specific question was, the value of property name password in the bean dataSource should be read from file for example, /vault/password

Comment: Your application context is *initialized* in "applicationContext.xml" (or equivalent), but there's some Java object somewhere that's *using* it.  You can't modify the .xml to somehow "read" the external file. The point is that you need to do it in Java.  *So what is the Java object*???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is probably your best bet:

> [How to correctly override BasicDataSource for Spring and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493743/)
>
> PROBLEM:
>
> Now I need to provide custom data source based on server environment
>   (not config), for which I need to calculate driverClassName and url
>   fields based on some condition.
>
> SOLUTION:
>
> Create a factory (since you need to customize only the creation phase
>   of the object, you don't need to control the whole lifetime of it).
>
> ```
>  public class MyDataSourceFactory {
>     public DataSource createDataSource() {
>         BasicDataSource target = new BasicDataSource();
>         if (condition) {
>             target.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");                
>             target.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?relaxAutoCommit=true"); 
>         } else { ... }
>         return target;
>     }
> }
> ```

In your case, your customization would do some I/O to set `target.password`.

Comment: The above solution works. Awesome. Answer is to write custom MyDataSourceFactory and provide that factory reference in application context file.